# passing date in ISODate object to mongoDB from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying `schema.aggregate({ $match: condition}, callback);`
and in this condition object am passing

```
condition = { dateAttempted: {$gt :"2015-01-01T10:51:04.197Z", $lte:"2015-12-01T10:46:02.520Z}}
```

It is not find any record.
But when i try this in mongo cmd

```
db.collections.aggregate({ $match: { dateAttempted: { $gte: ISODate("2015-01-01T10:51:04.197Z"), $lte: ISODate("2015-03-04T10:51:04.197Z") }}});
```

its working fine.

So how can i pass ISO date object from nodeJS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert those strings into JavaScript `Date` objects:

```
condition = { dateAttempted: {
    $gt: new Date("2015-01-01T10:51:04.197Z"), 
    $lte: new Date("2015-12-01T10:46:02.520Z")
}}
```

Comment: I also tried this.
This convert date into Thu Jan 01 2015 16:21:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) like that which is not my requirement.

Comment: @grishabh That's just the display string which defaults to showing the time in your local time zone.  Internally it's still the correct UTC time.

Comment: It is not returning any data.
It always return empty array.
So how can i find out records between this interval????

Comment: @grishabh Can you edit your question to show your actual code and a sample doc that you expect to be found, but isn't?